# How to change paragraph text in Javascript? (using values from radio buttons).(onclick event possibly not firing)

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

Basically, on my website I am attempting to have the option to choose between English and Spanish. How this would work is there would be two radio buttons, one for each language, and a button. When the button is pressed, the text of the paragraphs should be changed depending on the radiobutton that is checked. I have code which in my opinion should be valid but yet doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<html>

<head>

    <script type="javascript">
        function ChangeLanguage()
        {
            try
            {
                if(document.Radio.rbEnglish.checked)
                {
                    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "OF COURSE!";
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("p1".innerHTML = "CLARO!";
                }
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                alert(err.message);
            }
            return false;
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form name="Radio">

    <fieldset>

        <p>

            <input id="rbEnglish" name="rbLanguage" type="radio" checked="checked" value="English"/>

            <label for="rbEnglish">English</label>

            <input id="rbSpanish" name="rbLanguage" type="radio" value="Spanish"/>

            <label for="rbSpanish">Spanish</label>

            <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return ChangeLanguage();"/>

        </p>

    </fieldset>

    </form>

    <p id="p1">
OF COURSE!
    </p>

</body>

</html>
```

After some tampering it seems to me that the "onclick" event isn't working for some reason but I can't tell why. Please help either by correcting this code or offering alternative code.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? [Have you checked your console for errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because you are missing a ')'

Change this: 
   `document.getElementById("p1".innerHTML = "CLARO!";`

To this: `document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "CLARO!";`

See fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/4urqnxze/2/

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the error in my original code but somehow it still didn't work. Still, the fiddle code works and that's all that's necessary. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Check the console for any errors in the JavaScript. The first thing I noticed was a missing parenthesis.

```
document.getElementById("p1".innerHTML = "CLARO!";
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "CLARO!";
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that thanks. The code sadly still doesn't work though.

Comment: Dang. Check out the fiddle in Jake's answer and compare your code, that code seems to do what you want.